# PyCharm complains about needing a Python 2 SDK when attempting to display Epydoc docstrings

Tags: python, pycharm, twisted

I started to learn the Twisted Framework from a book called " Twisted Network Programming Essentials ". All good until I had to copy a server/client as an example on which I will follow some lessons from the book over these, everything works except for transporters, whatever is written in the parentheses after the transporter shows me that it is "Unexcepted argument", I want to specify when I hold the cursor on the transporter "write" it shows me this message: " You need a configured Python 2 SDK to render Epydoc docstrings ". Even with a new example from the twisted website, I have the same problem. I attached one SS .
PS: I have PyCharm as IDE.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

### Protocol Implementation

# This is just about the simplest possible protocol
class Echo(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        """
        As soon as any data is received, write it back.
        """
        self.transport.write(data) # <-- HERE IS MY PROBLEM


def main():
    f = Factory()
    f.protocol = Echo
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in PyCharm. Twisted's PyDoctor documentation generator can parse epydoc docstrings on Python 3 just fine; perhaps JetBrains should switch to that.

Comment: I updated the title to more clearly reflect your issue, because this has almost nothing to do with Twisted, beyond the docstring format it happens to use.